# Symfony2 / Doctrine : findBy with OneToMany cardinality

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I would like to if it possible (and how) to use a OneToMany relationship cardinality as findBy filter.

For instance here, let's say I have two entities `User` and `Post` with a OneToMany relationship between them so that an user has a collection of posts.

I am looking for a way to get all users that have at least one post, that is to say :
`|user.posts| >= 1`
or more programmatically `count(user->getPosts()) >= 1`

I know this can be achieved with a QueryBuilder or DQL but I am quite sure there is a trick that allows to make it work with `findBy`.

Here is the idea of what I am willing to do :

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myQuery()
    {
        return $this->findBy(
            array(... 'posts' ...), // What should I put here ?
            array('email' => 'ASC')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to use a querybuilder and set an having condition on the count on the post records

Comment: Isn't *having at least one post* the same as an inner join in this case? But what you want to do is not possible. For counting you need a group by clause, which is not available when using `findBy`.

Comment: You cannot search for the [association field, because it is the inverse side of an association](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php#L190-L203). Find methods only work on owning side associations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People in the comments are completely right, so I'm summing up:

- `findBy` won't work on a `OneToMany`, particularly since you want to find by the number of related entities.
- This means you have to use a `QueryBuilder`.

In your `UserRepository`, use the following:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('users')
    ->leftJoin('user.posts', 'posts')
    ->addGroupBy('users')
    ->having('COUNT(posts) >= :limit')
    ->setParameter('limit', 1);
```

- Since in your use case, the limit of `Posts` you want to select is 1, as said @Yoshi, you can use `INNER JOIN` instead of `GROUP BY` + `HAVING`, which will automatically unselect `Users` with no `Post`.

Instead of what is above, use this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('users')
    ->innerJoin('user.posts', 'posts');
```